# Loading values from many-to-many realtionship plus values from auto-generated table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on some kind of ambulance app and I need help on how to load relationship.

So, I have table appointment_statuses (and it is populated over the seeder because I need only 3 states - Done, In Progress, Not Performed), I have also the many-to-many relationship between the User model and Appointment model (appointment_user table which holds only IDs of both models) and now I am working on EMR system which means I can check all appointments that patient had in history.

Here is the image of the issue
[image]
So under "Status" I want to load name of that ID from appointment_statuses table instead to have only ID.

These tables have this structure:
Appointments
[image]

Status
[image]

These tables have these values:

Appointments table
[image]

Appointment statuses table
[image]

These are relations:

User:

```
 public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function patient()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Patient::class);
}

public function appointments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appointment::class);
}
```

Appointment:

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function appointmentStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AppointmentStatus::class);
}
```

Appointment_Statuses:

```
public function patient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
}

public function appointment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Appointment::class);
}
```

Here is a controller which is responsible for emr:
[image]

After I have added to controller this:

```
$user = User::with(['appointments', 'appointments.appointmentStatus'])->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

I get this in frontend:
`{{ dd($user->toArray()) }}`

[image]

**SOLUTION TO THIS ISSUE**
For anyone in future who gets this kind of issue just check the convention about the naming of the foreign keys. In my example, it was the issue, and if you are not sure that your foreign key name is correct then just in the model provide more information like this:

```
public function appointmentStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AppointmentStatus::class,'appointment_statuses_id','id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested relationship

```
    $user=User::with(['appointments','appointments.appointmentStatus'])
                ->where('id',$id)
                ->first();
```

Also you have to modify relationship

```
public function appointmentStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AppointmentStatus::class,'appointment_statuses_id','id');
}
```

Comment: On frontend I have 

`@foreach($user->appointments as $appointment)....` 

and then after that when I `dd` values it returns me null.

`{{ dd($appointment->appointmentStatus) }}`

Comment: try dd($user->toArray(); and post output

Comment: Here is the output of the dd($user->toArray()) https://prnt.sc/158ro0e

Also the question is edited so you can check it up there too :)

Comment: can you show appointments and status table structure

Comment: Images are uploaded :D

Comment: if any issue then let me know.but i am sure this will resolve your issue

Comment: omg, this will solve the issue for sure... I forgot that this name is not by convention and then I need to specify it ... Thank you so much hahaha

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in future who gets this kind of issue just check the convention about the naming of the foreign keys. In my example, it was the issue, and if you are not sure that your foreign key name is correct then just in the model provide more information like this:

```
public function appointmentStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AppointmentStatus::class,'appointment_statuses_id','id');
}
```